# Class 'PEAR_Error' not found in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 2032

Tags: php, pear

```
<?php
require_once "HTML/QuickForm.php";

$language=array(
'c#'=>'javascript',
'javascript'=>'javascript',
'perl'=>'perl',
'php'=>'php');

$form=new HTML/QuickForm("languages");

$form->addElement('text','username','yourname :',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>40));
$form->addElement('text','email','email address :',array('size'=>20,'maxlength'=>40));
$select=& $form->addElement('select','languages','your favorite<br /> Programing language',$language);
$select->multiple(1);
$form->addElement('submit',null,'Submit');
$form->display();
?>
```

When I Execute the above code using `xampp` I get the error

> Class 'PEAR_Error' not found in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTML\QuickForm.php on line 2032

How can I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
require_once 'PEAR.php';
```

to the top of your file.